# 'List<User>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-8.0

I'm working with an application on .NET Core 8 which uses EF and authentication with individual accounts.

I'm trying to display a list of users with their roles. The code is similar to this:

```
public IList<User> Users { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    IQueryable<User> users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Email = c.Email
    });

    Users = await users.ToListAsync();
}
```

To fix another bug I changed the users instance to call `ToList()`. The code looks like this now:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Role = c.Email
    }).ToList();

    Users = await users.ToListAsync();
}
```

And I'm getting the following compiler error.

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found.

The code isn't exactly like this. This is only a simplified code I'm showing. But to fix the first bug one thing to do is to call `ToList()` instead of using an `IQueryable`. And I modified the code to do that but I'm not sure how to get past the second bug. It would be helpful to know how to fix this kind of situation for my future use.

Comment: You don't need `Users = await users.ToListAsync();` as previous line returns the List. Only `IQueryable` contains the `ToListAsync` method definition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: Why not just  use `Users =  users;` ?

Comment: @YongShun There's an asynchronous piece of code in there which I have omitted. So the method needs to run asynchronously. If I do the modification you have kindly suggested I get a compiler warning saying the method will run synchronously.

Comment: That is fine, it is a compiler warning. Otherwise, you should change the method signature without `async`. `public void OnGet()`

Comment: PS: The link I shared on top should be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-8.0 for EF Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToListAsync` method is typically used on `IQueryable` to asynchronously retrieve the results from the database. However, when you call `ToList()` directly, you are working with an in-memory list, and there is no need for `ToListAsync`.

You should remove the unnecessary call to `ToListAsync`.

```
public void OnGet()
{
    var users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Role = c.Email
    }).ToList();

    Users = users;
}
```

If you were working with an `IQueryable` like, directly querying the database, then you would use `ToListAsync` to asynchronously fetch the results.

If you have an asynchronous piece of code and you want to keep the method asynchronous, then the `_userManager.Users` is typically an asynchronous operation, and you should keep the `async` and `await` in the method.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var users = await _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Role = c.Email
    }).ToListAsync();

    Users = users;
}
```

Comment: There's an asynchronous piece of code in there which I have omitted. So the method needs to run asynchronously. If I do this modification I get a compiler warning saying the method will run synchronously.

Comment: @Daneesha That warning is because you're using `ToList()` on the `IQueryable<User>` returned from your `_userManager.Users....` Linq query. Change it to use `await` with `ToListAsync()` - also, your `Select( c => new User() { ... } ` part seems redundant to me - is the `User` type used in `_userManager.Users` the same as the `User` in `new User`? If so, then you should remove that `.Select` entirely.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the comment. It helped me to find a combination that works. (I tried many variations so I have missed trying this one). No, the Select query isn't redundant. The User in _userManager and my custom User are different.

Comment: @Amit Mohanty Thanks for the answer. With Dai's comment I managed to find a combination that works.